# discord.js: How can I edit a sent message using the slash command, as it is done using the standard /me command

Tags: node.js, discord.js

How can I edit a sent message using the slash command, as it is done using the standard /me command: [command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuSWO.gif)

`PATCH /webhooks/<application_id>/<interaction_token>/messages/@original` sending me error "Unknown Webhooks"

Comment: Self-bot is against the Terms of Service.

Comment: @user15517071, please, more details